# XCode 8 Beta Documentation Generation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm currently exploring the latest Xcode Beta, and while doing so I'm watching some related WWDC videos. According to [this one](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/102/)(around 33rd minute) you can now have a quick code generation macro(similar to Eclipse and AS).

I'm unable to understand how to use this. Right after this we have a talk about xcode extension so it is possible this to be an extension however it's not clear to me - is it possible to have such feature with Xcode 8 beta?

Comment: Did you watch the video about Xcode extensions? What don't you understand about it? It puts you in charge of the text and you can do whatever you want.

Comment: I didn't understand whether this documentation is built-in or it could be eventually provided by 3rd party(me for example)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071289/xcode-8-auto-generated-quick-help-documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use this functionality or any Xcode Extensions on macOS 10.11 El Capitan, you need to follow the instructions in the Xcode 8 release notes:

- Launch Xcode 8 once so it can install required system components
- Open Terminal and run `sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl`
- Restart your Mac

This is currently necessary to tell the older operating system about the new Xcode Extension mechanism. It should not be necessary on any macOS Sierra beta.

Comment: Really strange today I launched Xcode and it required some additional tools to be installed. After that documentation tool started working like a charm. No need of terminal installation - I guess Xcode did the same by itself :)

Answer (score 4):

Okay first thing first - it is build in. And if anyone wonder where it is located, thanks to @Matthew Seaman I found it:

[image]

And as others pointed out - **it is not working with Version 8.0 beta (8S128d)**

Comment: Do we know if it has been disabled on Version 8.0 beta 2 (8S162m)? That option is always grayed out for me.

Comment: @AndyIbanez I'm seeing the same. I'm guessing the feature isn't there yet and instead of leaving it non-functional like it was in Beta 1, it's just grayed out now.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 8, you can place your cursor on a function or type declaration, and in the menu bar (just search under help for "documentation") you will find an item that will generate template documentation for you. This menu item also has a keyboard shortcut.

Yes, this is built-in, but it does not appear to be functional for me or others in Xcode 8 beta 1.

Comment: Anyone know how, or if it's possible, to change the /// to /**  ?

Comment: @Jorgen I've looked for this capability but can't seem to find it.