# Xcode stopped showing all functions description

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, autocomplete, xcode8

I'm on xcode8.3 and noticed like 2 days ago that the small description for all functions stopped showing on the autocomplete popup. I think they used to show at the bottom (maybe top) but not anymore.

I have restarted Xcode, and my computer and I also checked and I have downloaded the latest Xcode documentation. Like I said they use to show up before not to long ago.

[image]

Kinda annoying because another problem I have (as soon as I upgraded to xcode8.3) is that anything I type takes like 10-15 seconds to settle down and in the mean time it stays white and I can't do option+click to see the info.

Does anyone have any tips on what I could do for problem 1), and if you also know anything for problem 2) then that would be awesome.

**edit:** the first picture here [Xcode 8 how to show description of function while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40300275/4464916) explains what I am trying to say that I a missing, the little description of the function at the top, as a matter of fact if I start typing viewDidA... I will get the autocomplete popup, but I do not get the function description for any function.

Comment: Have you tried removing your derived data? Go to Preferences, click Locations, tap the arrow next to /Users/{User}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, close Xcode, and delete the contents of the folder DerivedData. Another thing that sometimes helps me in this situation is to hold down the Option key and choose "Clean Build Folder" from the Product menu. Also, another thing that sometimes works for me is to switch to a different file in the project and do a build, then switch back to the file where I was not getting autocompletions. Hope one of these helps.

Comment: updated post. Ive tried everything you listed in the past (is part of my daily morning routine because of problem 2), but, I am getting autocompletions as you can see from the picture. The problem is on the autocompletion window it used to show the description of the function (if declared in its source file of course) at the bottom of the autocomplete window, but now it doesn't.